# Log prefix property in LogAttirbute processor

Tags: apache-nifi

In my NiFi dataflow, am trying to log all the errors using "LogAttribute" processor (version: 1.5.0.3.1.2.0-7) with loglevel as "error" and LogPrefix as "JobName", So that BMC Patrol agent can identify the error message of my job uniquely using the keyword search "ERROR" along with "JobName" for generating Alarms. But in Nifi-App.log, though the Error message is getting captured, am not seeing the JobName as prefix for the log line. I tried assigning the JobName into a variable and used EL in the Log Prefix property as well. Still not working. Please correct if am missing anything here. Note: Except Loglevel & Log prefix, am retaining the default value for the other property fields.

Answer (score 0):

In LogAttribute the Log Prefix isn't really a prefix for all the lines, it is a prefix at the beginning of the logging for the given flow file. So if you search for your prefix you will probably see it once like "----- Prefix -----" followed by more lines with the attributes of the flow file.

You may want to try the LogMessage processor which looks like the Log Prefix works per line as you were expecting.

Comment: Yes Bryan. I searched the nifi-app.log file with the prefix i gave but i couldn't find. Not sure why. Also Log Message will display only the custom error message we are providing in the properties right? I want to capture actual error message coming out of the processors.

Comment: The error message from a previous processor is only available if that specific processor adds the error message as an attribute, which most of them don't